# Does Valla lose hatred on death?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Valla has a thing called Hatred, which builds up stacks as she performs auto-attacks.

Does dying cause Valla to lose Hatred stacks? Also, how do you tell how many stacks you have?

Comment: It's worth noting that Hatred falls off very rapidly when not actively in combat, so even if dying did not remove it there would be little functional difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, dying causes you to lose all of your hatred stacks.

You can tell how many stacks you have by checking the counter that appears to the right of your character portrait (this appears after you have at least one stack).

Hovering over the counter will show the current bonuses that are applied from your hatred stacks.

[image: Cropped screenshot showing the Hatred stacks icon circled in red]

Comment: The location of the counter has changed - it's now a third row under mana.  Took me a while to find it when I last played Valla.